# How can I make shell script to recursively scan a directory and add certain files based on their name patterns to Git?

Tags: linux, git, shell, unix

How can I make  shell script to recursively scan a cloned Git directory and remove certain files based on their name patterns?
If the file meet any of the below condition,

1. the file name length is more than 150 characters.  I don't mind the script include or exclude the extension. I don't need that much accuracy. An approximate number ~150 is enough.
2. The file contains a **:** (colon) in its file name.

If any of the file matches, it should be executed with `git rm </path/to/file/file name>`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `find` for the scanning:

```
find . -regextype egrep \( -name .git -prune \) -o \
       \( -type f -regex '.*(:[^/]*|[^/]{151,})$' -exec git rm '{}' \+ \)
```

(Do a dry run without the `-exec` bit first to make sure it works as desired, of course)

Note: This assumes GNU `find`, since you tagged the question `linux`.

This tells `find` to skip any `.git` subdirectories, and for all other regular files in the directory tree, if the last `/`-separated component (The filename + extension if any) has a colon or 151 or more characters in it, pass it off to `git rm`.

Comment: `-size` gets the **size** of the file, not the length of the name (the OP means filename). And I think `+` is better to be escaped: `\+`. Other than that it's a perfect solution!

Comment: `find . -not -name "*.git*" \( -name "*:*" -o -exec /usr/bin/test -l '{}' -gt 150 \) -exec git rm '{}' \+` References: [`find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) and [`test`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test).

Comment: Perhaps `test -l '{}'` could be further refined using [`basename`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/basename).

Comment: @phd I understand "file length" to be file size, not filename size. Did I miss a clarifying comment?

Comment: If it's name length, I have an idea that doesn't use `test`... Will update in a few

Comment: The OP wants to cleanup **filenames** to checkout the repository on Windows. :-) File sizes don't matter — filenames are. Filenames must be short and don't contain special characters.

Comment: … or perhaps not `basename` but `-execdir` in hope `find -execdir` passes just the name, not a full path…

Comment: @phd There's also nothing in his question that suggests Windows... anyways, see update.

Comment: File length 150 characters and colons — IMO it's nothing but preparing to checkout on Windows. Nice trick with `-regextype`! Upvoted.